# Sending logs from one serverless function to multiple cloudwatch groups

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fastapi, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I am developing an API for an app with python, using FastAPI, serverless and amazon web services.
We are using CloudWatch for saving our logs.
The thing is, I am required to send different logs to different groups in the same aplication, depending on wethever is it an error, an info, etc.

Let´s say, I have two log groups in CloudWatch: /aws/lambda/firstGroup and /aws/lambda/secondGroup.

An I have this function:

```
def foo(some_data):
    logger.info(f'calling the function with the data: {data}') # this goes to logGroup /aws/lambda/firstGroup
    try:
        doSomething()
    except:
        logger.error('ERROR! Something happened') # this goes to logGroup /aws/lambda/secondGroup
```

How can I configure the serverless.yml file so the logger.info goes to the first group and the logger.error goes to the second group?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt you can do that in the serverless.yml - rather you need to create your own `logger`s with different custom logic in them. The lambdas itself will always log to one specific log group / stream. This will be very difficult to achieve since the logging and sending to cloudwatch would now be part of your application logic itself, therefore it can fail and it can timeout, when the function timeouts your logs will not be written, etc.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for your answer. Could you please specify how can I select the log group in the logger function?
I suppossed that it would be in the serverless file, since I already specify the group there, following this documentation: [link](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-log)

Comment: The doc you mention is entirely unrelated to what you want. That documentation is for ***triggering*** your lambda based on cloudwatch events. As I said: you cannot do that log setup within serverless.yml, you need to write (A LOT) of custom code to get this to work. I cannot show you any code because I have not done it. Currently the lambda services takes care of forwarding everything on standard out to CW, you need to replicate ALL of that logic.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks again for your time.
If so, what do yo recommend to do for having the error logs in a sepparate place in AWS? What is the best/most common practise por this porpouse?

Comment: There is no common practice because that is nothing that is commonly done. If you want this you need to write a lot of code, no way around it.

Comment: An alternative would be to let your lambda log normally and have another lambda that is subscribed to the logstream of the first lambda, parses those logs and forwards the logs to a different log groups based on some text, e.g. the log level in the log messages.

Comment: @luk2302 I am going to search for some turn around, thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this solution with ec2 instance.

- create a log group
- create log stream
- then dump your logs

```
import boto3
import time


# init clients
clw_client = boto3.client('logs', region_name=REGION)


# print("check else create new log group..")
try:
    clw_client.create_log_group(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP)
except clw_client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
    pass

# print("check else create new log stream.....")
LOG_STREAM = '{}-{}'.format(time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S"),'logstream')
try:
    clw_client.create_log_stream(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP, logStreamName=LOG_STREAM)
except clw_client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
    pass
    
def log_update(text):
    print(text)
    response = clw_client.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName = LOG_GROUP,
        logStreamNamePrefix = LOG_STREAM
        )
    
    try:
        event_log = {
            'logGroupName': LOG_GROUP,
            'logStreamName': LOG_STREAM,
            'logEvents': [{
                'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
                'message': f"{time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\t {text}"
                }
            ],
        }

        if 'uploadSequenceToken' in response['logStreams'][0]:
            event_log.update({'sequenceToken': response['logStreams'][0] ['uploadSequenceToken']})

        response = clw_client.put_log_events(**event_log)
    except Exception as e:
        log_update(e)
```

Then use call that function inside your app whenever you like. Just don't check for `groups` and `stream` again and again for one job, these should run once.

You can update it, add more logic like change `log-group` name to implement what you wanted in this question with just some `if else` statements. Good luck!

Comment: This was actually very useful.
Thank you very much, Ashraf!